# How to apply Calculation In Interactive Grid Between 2 Columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to apply Calculation on two Columns in Interactive Grid that calculated value want to store in third non database column 
In the Below Image I want apply calculation on "QTY" and "Rate" and the Value store in Amount that is Non-Database..

[image: Click To View Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the Actions Button - Format - Compute, which will bring up a dialog to edit the calculation (note column names are referenced by the alias letters listed in the dialog).  After you get the calculation the way you like it, you can save it for next time with Actions - Save Report.  If you are logged in with developer access you can choose to save as "Default Report Settings" so that everyone gets your update as the default report.  Otherwise you can save to a named report that you just see on your login.